# Use SPServices in Sharepoint 2013 to display username

Tags: 2013, spservices

Has anyone managed to use SPServices to display the current logged in username in a content webpart?

Is this even possible in 2013 (online)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have your reasons why using SPServices for this mundane task, because the CSOM in SharePoint 2010 and even more in 2013 can help you do that using out-of-the-box routines. Of course it is only working in the current Site Collection.

See example here bellow:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,"sp.js");
var currentUser;

function init(){
 this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
 currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
 this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
 this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
 document.getElementById("currentUser").innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<div>Current Logged-In User:<label id="currentUser"></label></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, happy to do it anyway that works...but would prefer to achieve this via the SP ui rather than have use visual studio. Thanks for the input.

Comment: actually that code works perfectly directly in the CEWP, reason for which i've proposed it. Just wrap it in a script tab, put it in a .js file, via Notepad, upload it to a Document Library, add in the page a CEWP and reference the JS.

Comment: Hi There, I have this working on my site but its returning my full details i.e. i:0#.f|m​embership|developer@cndev.onmicrosoft.com​​​ where i would prefer to just have the Firstname or Firstname surname. Thanks again.

Comment: Stephen, it seems you use Claims - that is why you get the funny Account name. Available should be get_title(), but many other properties are only available via the User Profile (which of course requires at least Standard edition). See here for a exact example http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/05/11/retrieve-sharepoint-user-profile-property-value-with-jquery/ (you need to ask for FirstName and LastName)

Comment: Thanks for that...not sure if I have standard edition or not...I have seen this link blogpost http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html which looks promosing..

Comment: For SharePoint Online is at least Standard and it always come with User Profiles, and yes, that is exactly how you could use CSOM, which is also SP2013 specific as in 2010 it was not.

Comment: You can also do a simple GET using jQuery to the `_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is use JavaScript global variable _spUserId.  More read is available at

http://sympmarc.com/2013/03/26/using-_sppagecontextinfo-to-determine-the-current-sharepoint-context-in-script/